# how to avoid multiple request when using onedit on primefaces?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I´m using Primefaces 4.0 and I got an "onEdit" function inside a datatable that updates my record.
The thing is that if a user gets impatient and clicks the accept icon multiple times; it fire multiple times the request and and therefore it does the update multiple times.
So is there a way to make the "onEdit" show the pencil icon after the first click on the accept icon?
Here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable var="d" value="#{originadorMB.listOriginadorDetalleDTO}" id="addList" editable="true" 
    paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{d.idMensajeria}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
    selection="#{originadorMB.selectedOriginadorDetalleDTO}" selectionMode="single" 
    filteredValue="#{originadorMB.filteredListMensajerias}"
    emptyMessage="No hay registros" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,40" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        Mensajer&iacute;as
    </f:facet>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{originadorMB.onEdit}" update=":originadorForm:growl" />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{originadorMB.onCancel}" update=":originadorForm:growl" />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":originadorForm:growl" 
        listener="#{originadorMB.onRowDetalleSelect}"/>  
    <p:column id="idMensajeriaColumn" filterBy="idMensajeria" style="width:30%"
        headerText="Clave Mensajer&iacute;a" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{d.idMensajeria}" />
    </p:column>                            
    <p:column headerText="Activo">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="TRUE" value="#{d.activar}"/> 
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{d.activar}"/> 
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>                                                      
    </p:column>                        
    <p:column style="width:6%">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You also could use the blockUI primefaces component. Instead of disabling the ajax event, block the UI for further clicks until the first click is completely processed:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{originadorMB.onEdit}" 
      onstart="PF('blockUI').show();" oncomplete="PF('blockUI').hide();"/>

<p:blockUI block="addList" widgetVar="blockUI">
   <h:outputText value="Some Loading Text"></h:outputText>
   <h:graphicImage value="path/To/Loading.gif" />
</p:blockUI>
```

Beside the desired effect, blockUI provides you the possibility to show some loading information or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I somehow managed to solve my problem by disabling at the begging of my onEdit and enabling at the end of my onEdit.

```
                            <p:ajax disabled="#{originadorMB.disableEdit}" event="rowEdit" listener="#{originadorMB.onEdit}" 
                            update=":originadorForm:growl" async="true" />
```